# Fetch facebook user public data, which available without loggining througth Facebook Graph API if any exists

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api

I want to have additional public data for Facebook user, which is available on Facebook without logging. When I trying to get user data with Facebook Graph API I receive only few fields. But when I open user's Facebook page in browser(without logging on Facebook) it seems to give more additional data.

Example `https://www.facebook.com/juancarlos.rios.31` has more data than `https://graph.facebook.com/juancarlos.rios.31`. I use Graph API with access token and user page accessing on browser even not logging in Facebook.

Can anybody help with getting additional information?

Graph API response :

```
{
 "id": "1148615503",
 "name": "Juan Carlos Rios",
 "first_name": "Juan Carlos",
 "last_name": "Rios",
 "link": "link here",
 "username": "juancarlos.rios.31",
 "gender": "male",
 "locale": "es_LA"
}
```

when user page has additional info: books, music etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible unless you have an access token. The public graph doesn't reflect the browser information it reflects what is given in the documentation

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Comment: Thanks. Not good for me. So I must parse facebook page, or maybe there are any tricks?

Comment: @Aleksey no tricks other than scraping though the point of the API is not to avoid scraping. If you scrape don't be surprised if your IP gets black-listed